# Make goo effect only when it's in contact with the main shape

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using this as a pre-loader and it's working pretty good, but I'd like the "goo" effect to only happen when the moving shapes are actually in contact with the circle in the middle. See how the edges are all blurred up at all times now.

I like that the moving shapes blurs up right when they're in contact with the circle, but when they're at max away from it they should be 100% normal. The way the shape should look like when not in contact with the middle circle:

[image]

You can try to comment off the `url("#goo")` part to see the normal state as well.

```css
.page-preloader-cover {
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1200;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.cssload-dots {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 margin: auto;
 filter: url("#goo");
 -o-filter: url("#goo");
 -ms-filter: url("#goo");
 -webkit-filter: url("#goo");
 -moz-filter: url("#goo");
}

.svg-filter {
 position: absolute;
}

.cssload-dot {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 top: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%);
}

.cssload-dot:before {
 content: "";
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
 border-radius: 69px;
 background: #9664B4;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateY(0);
 -o-transform: translateY(0);
 -ms-transform: translateY(0);
 -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 margin-left: -24.5px;
 margin-top: -24.5px;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(5):before {
 z-index: 100;
 width: 62.5px;
 height: 62.5px;
 margin-left: -31.75px;
 margin-top: -31.75px;
 animation: cssload-dot-colors 4.6s ease infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-colors 4.6s ease infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-colors 4.6s ease infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-colors 4.6s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-colors 4.6s ease infinite;
}


.cssload-dot:nth-child(1) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 4.6s 0s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 4.6s 0s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 4.6s 0s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 4.6s 0s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-1 4.6s 0s linear infinite;
}
.cssload-dot:nth-child(1):before {
 background-color: transparent;
 animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 0s ease infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 0s ease infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 0s ease infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 0s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 0s ease infinite;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path style="fill:%2355AF32;" d="M 120 0 L 120 100 A 50 50 0 1 1 20 100 Z"></path></svg>') !important;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(2) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 4.6s 1.15s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 4.6s 1.15s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 4.6s 1.15s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 4.6s 1.15s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-2 4.6s 1.15s linear infinite;
}
.cssload-dot:nth-child(2):before {
 background-color: transparent;
 animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 1.15s ease infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 1.15s ease infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 1.15s ease infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 1.15s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 1.15s ease infinite;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path style="fill:%23ff4a49;" d="M 120 0 L 120 100 A 50 50 0 1 1 20 100 Z"></path></svg>') !important;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(3) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 4.6s 2.3s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 4.6s 2.3s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 4.6s 2.3s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 4.6s 2.3s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-3 4.6s 2.3s linear infinite;
}
.cssload-dot:nth-child(3):before {
 background-color: transparent;
 animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 2.3s ease infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 2.3s ease infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 2.3s ease infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 2.3s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 2.3s ease infinite;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path style="fill:%230A4B9B;" d="M 120 0 L 120 100 A 50 50 0 1 1 20 100 Z"></path></svg>') !important;
}

.cssload-dot:nth-child(4) {
 animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 4.6s 3.45s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 4.6s 3.45s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 4.6s 3.45s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 4.6s 3.45s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-rotate-4 4.6s 3.45s linear infinite;
}
.cssload-dot:nth-child(4):before {
 background-color: transparent;
 animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 3.45s ease infinite;
 -o-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 3.45s ease infinite;
 -ms-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 3.45s ease infinite;
 -webkit-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 3.45s ease infinite;
 -moz-animation: cssload-dot-move 4.6s 3.45s ease infinite;
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path style="fill:%239664B4;" d="M 120 0 L 120 100 A 50 50 0 1 1 20 100 Z"></path></svg>') !important;
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  transform: translateY(-96px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -o-transform: translateY(-96px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -ms-transform: translateY(-96px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-96px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-move {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 }
 18%, 22% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-96px);
 }
 40%, 100% {
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: #9664B4; /*#7a6cea*/
 }
 25% {
  background-color: #55AF32; /*#2be1df*/
 }
 50% {
  background-color: #E61423; /*#ff4a4a*/
 }
 75% {
  background-color: #0A4B9B; /*#3b55e6*/
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
 25% {
  background-color: #55AF32;
 }
 50% {
  background-color: #ff4a49;
 }
 75% {
  background-color: #0A4B9B;
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
 25% {
  background-color: #55AF32;
 }
 50% {
  background-color: #ff4a49;
 }
 75% {
  background-color: #0A4B9B;
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
 25% {
  background-color: #55AF32;
 }
 50% {
  background-color: #ff4a49;
 }
 75% {
  background-color: #0A4B9B;
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-colors {
 0% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
 25% {
  background-color: #55AF32;
 }
 50% {
  background-color: #ff4a49;
 }
 75% {
  background-color: #0A4B9B;
 }
 100% {
  background-color: #9664B4;
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-1 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(-105deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-2 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(165deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(540deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-3 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(435deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(810deg);
 }
}

@keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -o-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -o-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -ms-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-dot-rotate-4 {
 0% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(705deg);
 }
 100% {
  -moz-transform: rotate(1080deg);
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="page-preloader-cover">
     <div class="cssload-dots">
      <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
      <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
      <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
      <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
      <div class="cssload-dot"></div>
     </div>

     <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg-filter">
      <defs>
       <filter id="goo">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="12"></feGaussianBlur>
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" ></feColorMatrix>
       </filter>
      </defs>
     </svg>
   </div>
```

Comment: You could try reducing the `stdDeviation` on the gaussian blur as the shape moves away from the circle. And then increase it again when it gets nearer.  You can't do that with CSS animation though. You would need to use SMIL (ie SVGs built-in animation elements) or go with a Javascript solution. Eg. vanilla Javascript, or something like GSAP.

Comment: Thank you! I’m not that savvy when it comes to things outside of css. Any chance you could show a quick example? Would be fantastic! Thanks!

Comment: I was gonna try something like `window.setInterval (function () { 
    var pos = $('.cssload-dots .cssload-dot:nth-child(1)').position().left;
}, 25);` but it seems like I can't get the position of `:before`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your loader converted to SVG format.

The relevant part related to the blob blur is here:

```
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="12">
  <animate attributeName="stdDeviation"
           keyTimes="0; 0.5; 0.9; 1.0"
           values="12; 0; 0; 12"
           dur="1.15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</feGaussianBlur>
```

What's happening is that the blur reduces to 0 and back to 12 again every 1.15s to coincide with the movement of the shapes.  Over that 1.15sec interval, `stdDeviation` goes:

- from `12` at (0 * 1.15s) to `0` at (0.5 * 1.15s), then
- from `0` at (0.9 * 1.15s) to `12` at (1 * 1.15s)

IOW, the `keyTimes` values represent percentages of that 1.15s animation duration.  If you wish, you can tweak those `keyTimes` values to adjust the timing of the blur animation.

```css
.page-preloader-cover {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1200;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.page-preloader-cover svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-preloader-cover">

  <svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <filter id="goo">
        <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="12">
          <animate attributeName="stdDeviation"
                   keyTimes="0; 0.5; 0.9; 1.0"
                   values="12; 2; 2; 12"
                   dur="1.15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
        </feGaussianBlur>
        <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 18 -7" result="goo" ></feColorMatrix>
      </filter>
      
      <symbol id="shape" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
        <path d="M 120 0 L 120 100 A 50 50 0 1 1 20 100 Z"/>
      </symbol>
    </defs>

    <g transform="translate(100,100)" filter="url(#goo)">
      <animate attributeName="filter"
               keyTimes="0; 0.4; 0.9; 1.0"
               values="url(#goo); none; none; url(#goo)"
               dur="1.15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      <g>
        <use x="-24" y="-24" width="48" height="48" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#55AF32">
          <animate attributeName="y" dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                   calcMode="spline"
                   keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0"
                   keyTimes="0; 0.18; 0.22; 0.4; 1.0"
                   values="-24; -120; -120; -24; -24"/>
        </use>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          type="rotate" from="-105" to="270"
                          dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </g>
      <g>
        <use x="-24" y="-24" width="48" height="48" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#ff4a49">
          <animate attributeName="y" dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="1.15s"
                   calcMode="spline"
                   keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0"
                   keyTimes="0; 0.18; 0.22; 0.4; 1.0"
                   values="-24; -120; -120; -24; -24"/>
        </use>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          type="rotate" from="165" to="540"
                          dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="1.15s"/>
      </g>
      <g>
        <use x="-24" y="-24" width="48" height="48" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#0A4B9B">
          <animate attributeName="y" dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="2.3s"
                   calcMode="spline"
                   keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0"
                   keyTimes="0; 0.18; 0.22; 0.4; 1.0"
                   values="-24; -120; -120; -24; -24"/>
        </use>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          type="rotate" from="435" to="810"
                          dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="2.35s"/>
      </g>
      <g>
        <use x="-24" y="-24" width="48" height="48" xlink:href="#shape" fill="#9664B4">
          <animate attributeName="y" dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="3.45s"
                   calcMode="spline"
                   keySplines="0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0; 0.25 0.1 0.25 1.0"
                   keyTimes="0; 0.18; 0.22; 0.4; 1.0"
                   values="-24; -120; -120; -24; -24"/>
        </use>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          type="rotate" from="705" to="1080"
                          dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite" begin="3.45s"/>
      </g>

      <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="31.25" fill="#9664B4">
       <animate attributeName="fill" dur="4.6s" repeatCount="indefinite"
                 keyTimes="0; 0.25; 0.5; 0.75; 1"
                 values="#9664B4; #55AF32; #E61423; #0A4B9B; #9664B4"/>
      </circle>
    </g>
  </svg>

</div>
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant! Thank you so much! Only one last question, when the value is set to 0 the edges are kinda rough (compare to the black shape posted in my first message). Raising it to about 4 makes it better, but then it also rounds the edges a little too much. Is there a solution to this as well? Thank you!

Comment: You could try disabling the `filter` for the period it is 0.

Comment: That sounds like an option. Any hint on how to do it? Sorry, this is way over my head.

Comment: Is that a javascript thing? Also, is there any parameter that sets the time until it should start to animate? In the snippet above it starts right away, but I guess my site is a little heavy and while the css version starts animating right away, the svg version stays on the circle for 1-2 seconds before the shapes start coming out. The circle also starts out black on my site for that period of time. Ideas?

Comment: I've updated my example so that (a) it disables the filter when the shapes are separated, and (b) the circle is set to purple until the animation starts.  *"the svg version stays on the circle for 1-2 seconds"*. The animation won't start until the DOM is ready. I think that'll be the reason for the pause. Hard to tell without seeing your site tho.

Comment: You need to make as much content as possible be asynchronously loaded after your preloader animation starts.  How you do that will depend on the framework you are using.